# How to make loading effect like Office app in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control

Once open Office app, the title and elements of panorama "fly" into screen.
How to make this effect in my own app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add a reference to the [Silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) (also available via nuget), and then it's just some boiler plate code to add the transitions:

Add the assembly namespace:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

And then add, under the `PhoneApplicationPage` element:

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

There are other transitions available, and samples available from the Toolkit website...

Comment: I checked the demo. But no effect like built in Office app.

Comment: The Office App appears to use the turnstile transition (that I provided the sample XAML for in my answer) - it does affect different controls in different ways, so it maybe that the samples don't illustrate the effect on panoramas very well - best to try it in your app, and see if it's what you wanted.

Comment: I tried it in my app which doesn't have slash image and first page is panorama. Then there is still slide in effect when starting app. But exiting is turnstile.